# Does this query generated from typoscript in Typo3 11 make sense?

Tags: sql, typo3, typoscript

I build a menu from the categories of a storage page in Typo3 11 but I'm not getting the translations.
This is the select in typoscript:

```
lib.productsMenu = CONTENT
lib.productsMenu {
    table = sys_category
    select {
        pidInList = {$plugin.tx_products.productsCategoriesStoragePid}
        selectFields = sys_scategory.uid AS category_uid, sys_category.title AS category_title
        where = sys_category.uid != 28
        groupBy = sys_category.uid
    }...
```

That works just for the default language, I've tried MANY different ways and the issue seems to be always the same. This is the generated query:

```
SELECT ssys_category.uid AS category_uid, sys_category.title AS category_title, `sys_category`.`uid` AS `uid`, `sys_category`.`pid` AS `pid`, `sys_category`.`sys_language_uid` AS `sys_language_uid`, `sys_category`.`t3ver_state` AS `t3ver_state` 
FROM `sys_category` 
WHERE (`sys_category`.`pid` IN (105)) AND (sys_category.uid != 28) 
AND ((`sys_category`.`sys_language_uid` IN (0, -1)) OR ((`sys_category`.`l10n_parent` = 0) AND (`sys_category`.`sys_language_uid` = 1))) 
AND ((`sys_category`.`deleted` = 0) 
AND (`sys_category`.`t3ver_state` <= 0) 
AND (`sys_category`.`t3ver_wsid` = 0) 
AND ((`sys_category`.`t3ver_oid` = 0) OR (`sys_category`.`t3ver_state` = 4)) 
AND (`sys_category`.`hidden` = 0) 
AND (`sys_category`.`starttime` <= 1689343680) 
AND ((`sys_category`.`endtime` = 0) OR (`sys_category`.`endtime` > 1689343680))) 
GROUP BY `sys_category`.`uid`
```

It seems to me that there is something wrong because this part:

```
OR 
(
    (`sys_category`.`l10n_parent` = 0) AND (`sys_category`.`sys_language_uid` = 1)
)
```

Is gonna be always false right? If the language is not equal to 0 the l10n_parent is not gonna be 0 either. If the sys_language_uid is != 0 means that is a translation and l10n_parent must point to the parent row (the original language)

Is it something wrong with my typoscript or my language configuration on Typo3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you don't get the translated sys_category's is the `selectFields`in your select.

Read the description in the manual for the `selectFields`configuration:

https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/11.5/en-us/Functions/Select.html#selectfields

You need to include all relevant language fields in your select. Otherwise the TYPO3 internal localization will not succeed.

So you need to implement it like this:

```
lib.productsMenu = CONTENT
lib.productsMenu {
table = sys_category
select {
    pidInList = {$plugin.tx_products.productsCategoriesStoragePid}
    selectFields = sys_scategory.*
    where = sys_category.uid != 28
    groupBy = sys_category.uid
}
```